# Doxygen with custom annotations

Tags: java, annotations, doxygen

I couldn't really find anythingon this anywhere: i'd like to use custom annotations with doxygen. To be more exact, I  have an `@android` before every method thats supported on android, and would like doxygen to recognize, support and link his, similar to what it does with xrefitem. Is that possible?
The ultimate awesomeness would be to be able to do some light inference on this. For example, i'd like to infer he supportion level of  a class from the percentage of it's method that are annotated wih android. I knowhat i can do somthing like that with java and inspectors, i'm just not sure if i could do this with doxygen.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Here's a similar question, maybe it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610378/doxygen-dot-draw-link-between-classes-by-annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start with reading the documentation for \xrefitem here:

http://www.doxygen.org/commands.html#cmdxrefitem

you'll find that you can define custom commands via ALIASES, which are documented in more detail here

http://www.doxygen.org/custcmd.html

The computation of a 'coverage level' is not directly supported. You could check if you can use doxygen's XML output for that (see config option GENERATE_XML).

Comment: So, it's not possible to use java annotations? Coukd I at least get there half way by using annotation (@something not in a comment)  to get xrefitem behavior?