# Doxygen dot. Draw link between classes by annotation

Tags: java, javadoc, doxygen, graphviz, dot

Doxygen can generate class diagrams with graphiz.

For example:

```
class A {...};
class B extends A {...};
```

From this code I can generate a picture where doxygen can show that one class it the parent of an other.

But is there a way to generate a picture from code with manual references between classes?

For example when I describe DB scheme and use contract classes (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#DefineContract) I want to perform smth like this:

```
class MainClass {
    class A {
        String COLUMN_ID = "id_a";
    }

    /**
     * {@dotlinkto MainClass.A}
    **/
    @OrAnotationToDrawLink(A.class)
    class B {
        String COLUMN_ID = "id_b";
        String COLUMN_FOREIGN_KEY_TO_A = "id_a_key";
    }
}
```

And generate a picture of 2 classes A and B with reference between them.

I've tried to search through documentation but can't find any suitable examples or explanation about custom drawing in javadoc+doxygen+graphviz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest thing I can think of is to define a custom command that expands to an inline dot graph, i.e.

```
class MainClass {
  public class A {
    String COLUMN_ID = "id_a";
  }

  /**
   * @dotlinkbetween{A,B}
   * @cond
   **/
   @OrAnotationToDrawLink(A.class)
  /** @endcond */
   public class B {
      String COLUMN_ID = "id_b";
      String COLUMN_FOREIGN_KEY_TO_A = "id_a_key";
    }
}
```

with the following ALIAS definition in doxygen's configuration file:

```
ALIASES = dotlinkbetween{2}="@dot digraph { node [shape=record ]; \1 [ URL=\"\ref \1\" ]; \2 [ URL=\"\ref \2\" ]; \2 -> \1; } @enddot"
```

note that I had to use `@cond` ... `@endcond` to let doxygen skip the `@OrAnotationToDrawLink` line.

Comment: Seems like a solution for my case, one more question - is it possible to create only one occurance of each class on graph? For example in this case (http://dimlix.com/screens/2014_09_d(001).png) get only 1 occurance of GroupStudentEntry?

Comment: And maybe print not only a name of the class, but also params like in class diagramm: http://dimlix.com/screens/2014_09_d(002).png